# How do I insert content inside a filter button without duplicating

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way of inserting content inside a filter button without duplicating it?

For example, if you see the content in this case "Hello world" is duplicated inside the filter collapse button.

The idea is to show content without a filter button on large and medium devices and collapsable on small devices, so user can collapse the content if required. This will save the length of the page and give good UX/UI.

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    Hello world
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
  <hr>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar-collapse">Filter</button>
    <div id="sidebar-collapse" class="collapse filter-collapse">
    Hello world
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems unclear what you want exactly. Can you create a Codepen?

Comment: Here's it: https://jsfiddle.net/kzry57s0/

Comment: I don't see any JS there. What should happen on doing what?

Comment: So what I want is: If you see the content in col-6 which is "Hello world". It should go inside the button collapse on small devices without duplicating it.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/s7w6op

Answer (score 0):

This is a contrived example but you could maintain a variable with the text, and use `window.matchMedia` to check the device dimensions and dynamically add or remove that text. Something like:

```
function addText(query) {
  const text = document.createTextNode("Hello world");
  if (query.matches) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    sidebar.appendChild(text);
    desktop.innerText = '';
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    desktop.appendChild(text);
    sidebar.innerText = '';
  }
}
const desktop = document.getElementById('desktop-div');
const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar-collapse');
const query = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 350px)");
addText(query);
query.addListener(addText);
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/be9spz6w/1/) the updated JSFiddle.

But I believe it is simpler to just keep duplicate text and hide or show it depending on the device using CSS media queries.

Comment: Is it not possible with pure HTML/CSS?

Comment: I don't know how.